# What exactly determines how long it takes a given miner to mine 1 btc block? (not talking about hashrate)

Tags: mining-theory, algorithms

So given the number of miners out there working on doing the same thing and that 1 block is mined every 10 minutes, it would appear at face value that only those with the highest hashrates would ever be able to earn a block reward as they would have to complete a new block in 10 minutes or less.

This is obviously not the case since lower hashrate hardware can still successfully mine blocks, albeit at a slower rate.

Is each miner starting at a different nonce and just getting lucky or is there some other variable that allows even slower miners to finish a block in 10 minutes?

What am I missing?